# Loading resources with webkitgtk+

Tags: c, webkit, gtk

When I call webkit_web_view_load_string() to load a html content into
a webkitview, webkit always refuses to load local files or resources (css, javascript, images) referred in the html content.

Note :  i'm using GResource for loading resources into the binary?.
this is un example :

```
GBytes *data;
GResource *resource;
GByteArray* gbarray;  resource = one_file_get_resource();

.
```

.
.
.

```
g_resources_register (resource);
data = g_resource_lookup_data (resource,"/com/test/resources/index.html", G_RESOURCE_LOOKUP_FLAGS_NONE,NULL);
gbarray  = g_bytes_unref_to_array(data);
const gchar* data_char = gbarray->data;
```

.
.
.

```
webkit_web_view_load_string(webView, data_char, NULL, NULL,"");
```

This is my xml file for GResources :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/test">
    <file>resources/index.html</file>
    <file>resources/style.css</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Now my problem is that index.html is loaded but without the css file. I got my html file without styling!! How can i solve this and thanks?!

Answer (score 1):

You should somehow tell WebKit that it is okey to load local resources. You can do this by using `webkit_web_view_load_uri` and making sure that you use a `file://` URI. Otherwise, WebKit will assume that the string (in load_string) comes from an untrusted sources, hence is not allowed to access local resources.

Comment: Using file:// work surely but what i want is to embed all resources with the exutable app during build. that make me able to run app from any other pc without moving resources from a place to another that why i used GResoures Framework.